# why is this simple regex not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed, scripting

i'm brushing up on my regex, seeing what i can do and also narrowing my standard coding style in it. then i wrote a small snippet that should've worked, but won't. so i kept reducing it to the most basic form, and still not doing i want it to do:

```
echo "a" | sed -e 's/a+/A/g'
```

why does it not output

```
A
```

i'm just bewildered why this doesn't work...

Comment: + is a extended regular expression .using -r

Comment: @KalanidhiM. It can be used in POSIX regexes too, but you need to escape it: `\+`. But the `+` is simply not required here

Comment: An alternative to `a+` which is a metacharacter representing one or more `a`'s is `aa*` which represents an `a` followed by zero or more `a`'s. N.B. `+` is GNU enhancement and needs to be escaped or the `-r` switch enabled whereas `aa*` is available in in all seds.

Comment: I had no idea sed doesn't handle the plus quantifier. Why do people use this primitive dinosaur ?

Comment: @sln `sed` does support the `+` quantifier. You'll have to escape it unless you are using the `-r` command line option. Believe it or not, `sed` is the perfect tool for a lot of tasks related to editing text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work with this syntax you need to make sure `sed` interprets the regular expression as an extended regular expression.

To do this you can use the `-E` on Mac OSX:

```
echo "a" | sed -E -e 's/a+/A/g'
```

or the `-r` flag on linux:

```
echo "a" | sed -r -e 's/a+/A/g'
```

Comment: Why is the `+` required here at all? Note that you can use `+` even in simple regexes but you need to escape it then: `\+`

Comment: In this case the `+` is not required, but since the OP wrote that this is a reduced example I guess the original case does require it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `+`. If you want to replace every lowercased `a` by an uppercased `A` you can use this:

```
echo "abcdabdbda" | sed 's/a/A/g'
```

Output:

```
AbcdAbdbdA
```

The `+` is a special character in a regex. It matches the preceding character or group at least one or multiple times. You don't need it here.

Note: If you use `+` in a standard sed regex pattern you would need to escape it: `\+` to give it is special meaning. Without escaping it will be threatened like a literal `+`.

Comment: Maybe he wants to consolidate multiple `aaa`'s into a single `A` ?

Comment: The question is too unclear to say that. I assume he was aware of the difference between `/g` and `+`.. But not sure..